# How to disable watchdog table entry?

Tags: 8, log-messages

My drupal 8 watchdog entry running very vastly. I want to stop the watchdog entry for few times immediate basis and resolve the issues. Please suggest.

Comment: You can lower it to `100` over at `/admin/config/development/logging`

Comment: so it will keep on 100 log entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Database Logging (`dblog`) is responsible for logging to the Watchdog table. Uninstall the module and it will remove the table and logging to it.